# Handle notification click in background

Tags: android

I have added two action button to the notification but I'm not able to handle the click event in background.

```
Intent ok = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
ok.putExtra("OK",true);
PendingIntent intentOK = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0 , ok, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_ok, delivered(), intentOK);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_ko, notdelivered(), intentKO);
```

The actions needs an intent that force my app in foreground.

I need to post user choice to a remote server without popping up the app.

Comment: Use a broadcast `PendingIntent`, triggering a `BroadcastReceiver`. Or, use a service `PendingIntent`, triggering a `Service`.

Comment: If you provide more background of your problem, the answer you will get will be more tailored. Now, your question it too broad and community has to guess some details.